# How to fill empty space of screen by Datatable rows?

Tags: flutter

I have a datatable that are filled by results from mysql. The number of rows depends on the number of results from the mysql. I need to the DataTable fill by rows all empty screen space, whatever of the number of mysql results. In other words: the top of DataTable rows will be filled, and the bottom ones will be empty if number of results is less than the rows number.
How it works now:

```
SingleChildScrollView _dataColumn() {
return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: CustomDataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
          label: Text('Teachers'),
        ),
      ],
      rows: _filterEmployees
          .map(
            (employee) => DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text(
                  employee.teachName,
                ),
                onTap: () {
                 ...
                  });
                },
              ),
            ]),
          )
          .toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [List Generate](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.17.1/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) for a fixed number of iterations and mapping over the number in the employees.

```
SingleChildScrollView _dataColumn() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: CustomDataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Teachers'),
              ),
            ],
            rows: 
              List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i).map((num) {
                if (num < _filterEmployees.length) {
                  return _filterEmployees[num];
                }

                //Default Employee object
                return Employee();
              }).map((employee) => DataRow(cells: [
                   DataCell(
                     Text(
                       employee.teachName,
                     ),
                     onTap: () {
                       ...
                     });
                 },
               ),
           ]),
          )
          .toList(),
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now your `Datatable` will always consist of 10 entries, first entries will be filled but later on there will be empty entries.

Comment: Thanks! To avoid errors related with the absence of text in the bottom lines, need to change the text in DataCell: Text(employee.teachName!=null?employee.teachName:''),

Comment: Yes you should be doing that or have a default constructor implementation